# Is there a way to return SELECT results sorted by order of "WHERE IN" values?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Say I have a call

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE id IN (5,3,8,9);
```

That returns the results in the id order of 3,5,8,9.  Is there any way to get it to return the results in the given 5,3,8,9 order?

Comment: If the values in `IN` is a little you can use `ORDER BY CASE` construct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE id IN (5,3,8,9)
ORDER BY 
CASE id
    WHEN 5 THEN 1
    WHEN 3 THEN 2
    WHEN 8 THEN 3
    WHEN 9 THEN 4
    ELSE 5
  END
```

**[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b27aa/1)**

Answer (score 4):

Another option which is a bit more flexible because you only need to change the ids once.

```
with id_list (id, sort_order) as (
  values (5,1), (3,2), (8,3), (9,4)
)
select t.*
from tablename
  join id_list l on l.id = t.id
order by l.sort_order;
```

Maintaining the sort_order is however somewhat ugly if you need to insert new ids.

With the upcoming 9.4 this will be even easier:

```
with id_list (id, sort_order) as (
   select *
   from unnest(array[5,3,8,9]) with ordinality
)
select *
from tablename
  join id_list l on l.id = t.id
order by l.sort_order;
```

This *can* be done using pre 9.4 but this relies on the order of the unnest function which is **not** *guaranteed* to give a consistent ordering (but in reality it seems to be always the same):

```
with id_list (id, sort_order) as (
   select *, row_number() over ()
   from unnest(array[5,3,8,9]) 
)
select *
from tablename
  join id_list l on l.id = t.id
order by l.sort_order;
```

Comment: You could probably JOIN to a `generate_series` to supply the `sort_order` values too.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this by using an explicit `join`:

```
with vals as (
      select 5 as id, 1 as ordering union all
      select 3, 2 union all
      select 8, 3 union all
      select 9, 4
     )
select t.*
from tablename t join
     vals v
     on t.id = v.id
order by v.ordering;
```

This allows you to create the list only once.

Comment: But can you use a VALUES expression in the CTE instead of all those nasty unions? You can JOIN to a VALUES expression if you use enough parentheses but I'm not sure about wrapping it in a CTE.

Answer (score 0):

In postgres, use POSITION:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE id IN (5,3,8,9)
ORDER BY POSITION(',' || id || ',' IN ',5,3,8,9,')
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/87c50/2)

---

In mysql, use the [`FIELD()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field) function:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE id IN (5,3,8,9)
ORDER BY FIELD(id,5,3,8,9)
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/87c503/1)

Comment: There is no `field()` function in Postgres

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name sorted..., but a +1 2 u 2

Answer (score 0):

You try this alternative also

```
select *
from Table1
where id in (5,3,8,9)
order by position(id::text in '5,3,8,9')
```

[**sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b27aa/2)

---

[**position**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-SQL)

Comment: This wouldn't work if you have an id `5` and `55` where `55` should be sorted _before_ `5`

Comment: Wouldn't this fail for `id=1` and `IN(10,1)`?

Answer (score 0):

```
-- some data
DROP SCHEMA tmp CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA tmp ;
SET search_path=tmp;

CREATE TABLE tablename
        ( id serial PRIMARY KEY
        , blah integer
        );
INSERT INTO tablename(blah)
select gs
FROM generate_series(1,10) gs;

-- The query
SELECT * FROM tablename t
JOIN ( SELECT id
        , row_number() OVER () AS rnk
        FROM unnest(array[ 5,3,8,9]  ) AS id
        ) val USING(id)
ORDER BY val.rnk
        ;
```

The result:

```
DROP SCHEMA
CREATE SCHEMA
SET
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 10
 id | blub | rnk 
----+------+-----
  5 |    5 |   1
  3 |    3 |   2
  8 |    8 |   3
  9 |    9 |   4
(4 rows)
```